# Is it possible to render frames in Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am pulling h264 and AAC frames and at the moment I am feeding them to MediaCodec, decoding and rendering them myself, but the code is getting too complicated and I need to cover all cases. I was thinking if it's possible to set up an Exoplayer instance and feed them as a source.

I can only find that it supports normal files and streams, but not separate frames? Do I need to mux the frames myself, and if so is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you are extracting frames from a video file or a live stream, and then want to work on them individually or display them individually, you may find that OpenCV would suit your use case.

You can fairly simply open a stream or file, go frame by frame and do what you want with the resulting decoded bitmap.

This answer has a Python and Android example that might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58921325/334402

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was a bit confusing. I mean I want to playback a live stream in the form of individual audio and video frames.

Comment: @Lucifer893, do you mean you want to connect to the live stream as normal but only show, for example, every 100th frame?

Comment: No, I mean render actual video frames as oposed to stream or file. Bytebuffers.

Comment: To decode an individual video frame you typically need the other frames around it, as encoders often refer to previous and sometimes next frames when encoding the current frame. Is this the problem you are trying to resolve?

Comment: Yes, I have all the frames, I can pull them one by one from a source. But not sure how to set up a custom datasource for h264 frames.